# Run spark unit test on Windows

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to run some transformation on **Spark**, it works fine on cluster (YARN, linux machines).
However, when I'm trying to run it on local machine (**Windows 7**) under unit test, I got errors:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:318)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:333)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:326)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:93)
```

My code is following:

```
@Test
def testETL() = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "test", conf)
    try {
        val etl = new IxtoolsDailyAgg() // empty constructor

        val data = sc.parallelize(List("in1", "in2", "in3"))

        etl.etl(data) // rdd transformation, no access to SparkContext or Hadoop
        Assert.assertTrue(true)
    } finally {
        if(sc != null)
            sc.stop()
    }
}
```

Why is it trying to access hadoop at all? and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue on my own http://simpletoad.blogspot.com/2014/07/runing-spark-unit-test-on-windows-7.html